# Return specific value from json if it exist and zero rows if not

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this nested json-structure in a column named schema:

```
{"fields" : {"Kommune2015" : {"0101" : "Halden", "0104" : "Moss" }}}
```

I can get a value using:

```
select schema::jsonb#>>'{fields,Kommune2015,0101}' from meta;
 ?column?
---------
Halden
(1 row)
```

But if I query a key that does not exist I still get

```
select schema::jsonb#>>'{fields,Kommune2015,010}' from meta;
 ?column?

----------
(1 row)
```

Adding a where-clause will return a value if the key exist:

```
select schema::jsonb#>>'{fields,Kommune2015,0101}' from meta where schema::jsonb#>>'{fields,Kommune2015,0101}' is not null;
```

Is it possible to shorten this query so the key doesn't have to be explicitly named twice?

This is version 10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery or a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html). For example

```
with things as (
    select schema::jsonb#>>'{fields,Kommune2015,0101}' thing from meta
)
select thing from things where thing is not null
```